# Select distinct group of records only when all of the records' certain column is of a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 8 records below:

```
ID   | Common ID | Reject
-------------------------
AB-1 | AB        | NULL
AB-2 | AB        | YES
AB-3 | AB        | NULL
BB-1 | BB        | YES
BB-2 | BB        | YES
BB-3 | BB        | YES
CB-1 | CB        | YES
CB-2 | CB        | YES
DB-1 | DB        | NULL
```

My expected result is:

```
ID   | Common ID | Reject
-------------------------
BB-1 | BB        | YES
CB-1 | CB        | YES
```

I only want to obtain distinct records when the reject column is yes for all of the records with the same Common ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select min(ID), [Common ID], max(Reject)
from tablename
group by [Common ID]
having count(*) = count(case when Reject = 'YES' then 1 end)
```

If a [Common ID] has the same number of rows as the number of YES, then return it!

The `HAVING` clause's `count(*)` returns the total number of rows for a `[Common ID]`. The `case` expression returns 1 if Reject = Yes, otherwise null. The right side `count` returns the number of rows where the case returns a non-null value (i.e. when Reject is yes!) When the same number of rows, `HAVING` is true!

**Edit:**

In this specific case, when the Reject column's values seem to be either YES or NULL, the `HAVING` can be simplified as:

```
having count(*) = count(Reject)
```

However, if other values (like NO) later will be found in the column, this won't work. So I recommend the original `HAVING` clause!

Comment: Nice... btw, what is the actual value of `count(*) = count(case when Reject = 'YES' then 1 end)`? I don't really understand this line. Can you show me the values of `count(*)` and the corresponding value of `count(case when Reject = 'YES' then 1 end` for each looping?

Comment: @Markorie, added explanation to my answer. (Too long for being a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), CommonID, MIN(Reject) as Reject
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY CommonID
HAVING  MIN(ISNULL(Reject, ''))  = MAX(ISNULL(Reject, ''))
AND     MIN(ISNULL(Reject, '')) = 'Yes'
```

EDIT : as you have NULL value, will need to use ISNULL() on the column

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query with a `GROUP BY` in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT ID, [Common ID], Reject
FROM yourtable
WHERE (SELECT SUM(LEN(a.Reject)) 
       FROM yourtable a 
       WHERE ID = a.ID 
       GROUP BY a.ID) IS NULL
```

Output:

SQL Fiddle:

Answer (score 0):

Using `row_number` window function and `not exists`. A little bit complicated but should do the work:

```
with cte as(select *, row_number(partition by commonid order by id) rn from table)
select c.* 
from cte c
where c.rn = 1 and 
      not exists(select * from table t 
                 where t.commonid = c.commonid and 
                       (t.reject is null or t.reject <> 'yes'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, [Common ID], MIN(Reject) as Reject
FROM   Table1
GROUP BY [Common ID]
HAVING  MIN(ISNULL(Reject, '')) = 'YES'
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you**

```
select
(select top 1 ID from YourTable where CommonID= t.CommonID and reject=t.reject)ID,
CommonID,
Reject
from YourTable T
group by
CommonID,reject
having (Reject is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, ColumnID, MIN(Reject) AS Reject
       FROM tableName
       WHERE Reject='YES' AND ID LIKE '%1'
       GROUP BY ColumnID
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest way to achieve your expected result.

```
 SELECT ID, [Common ID], Reject
 FROM YOURTABLE
 WHERE REJECT = 'YES'
 GROUP BY ID, COMMON ID
```